# Rails handling ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch as exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, exception

I have the following code:

```
def set_tags_from_string
    list = self.tags_string.split(/ /)

    list.each do |tag|
        begin
            self.partner_tags << PartnerTag.find_by(name: tag)
        rescue
            self.partner_tags << PartnerTag.create(name: tag)
        end
    end
end
```

The problem comes when I try pushing a `PartnerTag` into `self.partner_tags` and that tag doesn't exist yet. The console shows the following:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: PartnerTag(#28272720) expected, got NilClass(#8501040)
```

I was hoping to be able to handle this as an exception but it still gives the error. I've never done exception handling in Ruby before so I figure I might be missing something, but I followed [this](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html) tutorial and I don't see what I'm missing. The Rails API says that it is in fact an exception which ends up inheriting from `StandardError`. [The Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/StandardError.html) says that a rescue clause should handle all `StandardError`s, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
self.partner_tags << PartnerTag.find_by(name: tag) || PartnerTag.create(name)
```

Also if you are on Rails 4, you can do:

```
self.partners_tags << PartnerTag.find_or_create_by(tag: name)
```

Note however that it doesn't prevent you from ending up with two identical tags unless you have unique constraint in a database.

Comment: `PartnerTag` has a uniqueness validation in the class definition. That should be equivalent to a db constraint when it comes to preventing two identical tags right?

Comment: @Hugo - I had a discussion on this yesterday and unfortunately it does not. There might be two processes working in parallel, check for tag existence at the same time and then each of them will create a new one. This should not happen with single-threaded servers like webrick, however it will became a seriouus issue if you decide to use Unicorn or if your app is being run on multiple servers.